# Regular Expression to exclude specific pattern in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select html attributes based on Regular expression. 
Follwing is the strings it is matching based on follwoing regular expression for below HTML markup.

```
     colspan="2"
     bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
     height="28"
     psdtyle="font-stretch: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5;"
     align="center"
     style="word-wrap: break-word; margin: 5px 0px;"
     size="2"
```

((\w+)="[a-zA-Z#-:0-9 ;]*")

Now the real question is I want to exclude colspan, i.e colspan="2" should not match.

```
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" psdtyle="font-stretch: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5;">
     <p align="center" style="word-wrap: break-word; margin: 5px 0px;"><font size="2">Shoulder</font></p>
  </td
```

Comment: Please spell check your title and post. By the way, don't use regexp to analyze HTML. Also, why are you using HTML attributes as if it were 2006?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the elements `attributes` within a `for` loop, use `if` condition to exclude `colspan` attribute

```js
var td = document.querySelector("tr td");
var attrs = td.attributes;
for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
  if (attrs[i].name !== "colspan")
  console.log(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" psdtyle="font-stretch: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5;">
     <p align="center" style="word-wrap: break-word; margin: 5px 0px;"><font size="2">Shoulder</font></p>
  </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should do the trick:

```
((\b(?!colspan\b)(\w+))\s?=\s?["'][a-zA-Z#-:0-9 ;]*["'])
```